# Programming R - Error in if (errors) return(odbcGetErrMsg(channel)) else return(invisible(stat)) :

Tags: mysql, r

I am new to R and I am trying to do something that feels simple but cant get my code to work.

When I run my code (sqlQuery and which saves the data to a SQL database) it works fine with the database name but when I use an object as the database name instead of the actual name I get the following error -Error in if (errors) return(odbcGetErrMsg(channel)) else return(invisible(stat)) :argument is not interpretable as logical

The way I am using the object name in my R code is for example is select * from  ",object,".dbo.tstTable The object dataBase is the date of every previous Friday.

`StartCode(Server = "Server01",DB=dataBase,WH=FALSE) POLICYLIST <- sqlQuery(channel1," SELECT DISTINCT [POLICY_ID] FROM ",dataBase,".[dbo].[policy] ") StartCode(Server = "SERVER02",DB="DataQuality",WH=FALSE) sqlQuery(channel1,"drop table DQ1") sqlSave (channel1, POLICYLIST, "DQ1")`

Comment: Could you please provide the actual code you've used that led you to this error? It would be preferable if it were [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please see my code below. The object dataBase is the date of every previous Friday. StartCode(Server = "Server01",DB=dataBase,WH=FALSE)
POLICYLIST <- sqlQuery(channel1,"
SELECT DISTINCT [POLICY_ID] FROM ",dataBase,".[dbo].[policy] ")
StartCode(Server = "SERVER02",DB="DataQuality",WH=FALSE)
sqlQuery(channel1,"drop table DQ1")
sqlSave (channel1, POLICYLIST, "DQ1")

Comment: Please edit your code into your question (and format it according to the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) so that we can read it and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out why my code was not working I changed my code to the below to make it work. I just needed to add paste. appologies for my stupid question!

```
StartCode(Server = "Server01",DB=dataBase,WH=FALSE) POLICYLIST <- sqlQuery(channel1, paste" SELECT DISTINCT [POLICY_ID] FROM ",dataBase,".[dbo].[policy] ")) StartCode(Server = "SERVER02",DB="DataQuality",WH=FALSE) sqlQuery(channel1,"drop table DQ1") sqlSave (channel1, POLICYLIST, "DQ1")
```